# Comparing Expected vs Observed with almost no information

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have a game with somewhat intrincate rules regarding its prizes (it's vide-bingo). Thankfully, we managed to find out the expected mean $\mu_0$, for the liniarity of the Expected Value. Even though, we can't do the same with variance, so we don't know the standard deviation $\sigma_0$

We have $n$ simulations of the random variable $X$, which returns the amount won, with unkown distribution, with mean $\mu_x$ and standard deviation $\sigma_x$. Sadly, we have no access to individual values $x_i$ so we can't calculate $Var(X)$ nor $sd$, we only have $\tilde x$.

How would you do an hypothesis test for $H_0: \mu_x = \mu_0$?

My first approach was to look for $P(Z>\mid\frac{\tilde x-\mu_0}{\sqrt{\mu_0}}\mid)$ but seems a bit off, since when I change the scale, the probability changes.

---

Edit: I know how to do the Hypothesis Test if I'd knew the $sd$ and I know also how to calculate it. The problem is that due to the nature of the simulations, that's not something I can keep track of. So the question is whether it's possible or not to make an Hypothesis Test without using Standard Deviation of any. Or making some kind of estimate using only means (which would seem weird)

Comment: I assume each of the $n$ indep. simulations is based on many iterations $B$ and that each generates a prize value $X_i.$ You average these $X_i$ to get $\bar X$ as an estimate of $\mu_x.$ Similarly, you should be able to find the SD $S$ of the $X_i$ to estimate $\sigma_X.$ For example, if $n$ is large, a 95% CI for $\mu$ is $\bar X \pm 2S/\sqrt{n}.$ (If smaller, use t dist'n to see what to use instead of 2.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long, hopefully helpful, Comment. Not even close to an Answer.

First, $H_0 : \mu = \bar x$ is not a reasonably posed
null hypothesis. The null hypothesis is expressed in terms
of *parameters,* never anything derived from data. 
(And in a continuous distribution there is essentially 0 chance
that $\mu = \bar x.$)

Second, I do not see how it is possible to test a null
hypothesis about a population mean $\mu$ based on $\bar X,$
but with no idea about the variance of the population or
sample. If this is an exercise that refers back to an example,
perhaps the population standard deviation (SD) $\sigma$ or
variance $\sigma^2$ is given there. Or maybe the actual 
data are there so you can estimate $\sigma$ as the sample
SD $S$. (You would not compute a population variance $Var(X)$ from data. From data you might compute an *estimate* of it.)

There are enough misconceptions about terminology and notation
in your Question, that I think you need to read the accompanying
material very carefully and try to edit your question accordingly.

I see you have been active on this site with probability and
combinatorics Q & A. Guess you may be just starting with
statistics. Lots of new ideas, terminology and notation to
absorb.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Bruce. I tried to edit the question to fit a bit more what I really wanted to ask. By the way, the only reason why I posted it is because I found myself in this situation when trying to check if one of my simulations (of random events) was ok and didn't know how to really check.

Comment: But if it's your simulation, don't you have some access to info about the variance? Leave additional info about simulation if you want to pursue it.

Comment: I stimulate video bingo games, for which the expected value is easy to calculate but the variance is a hell (impossible for me, it would take eons for my computer to check all possibilities)

Comment: In Bingo don't you either win or lose? If it's binomial, of course variance is easy. Even if not binomial, you must average _something_ to find the mean, and that something should give you info on variance. Please edit Question if you have another clue to offer about variability.